# What are reasons to prefer increasing the number of task managers instead of task slots per task manager?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

According to [the Flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/concepts/runtime.html#task-slots-and-resources), there exist two dimensions to affect the amount of resources available to a task:

1. The number of task managers
2. The number of task slots available to a task manager.

> Having one slot per TaskManager means each task group runs in a separate JVM (which can be started in a separate container, for example). Having multiple slots means more subtasks share the same JVM. Tasks in the same JVM share TCP connections (via multiplexing) and heartbeat messages. **They may also share data sets and data structures, thus reducing the per-task overhead.**

With this line in the documentation, it seems that you would always err on the side of increasing the number of task slots per task manager instead of increasing the number of task managers.

A concrete scenario: if I have a job cluster deployed in Kubernetes (let's assume 16 CPU cores are available) and a pipeline consisting of one source + one map function + one sink, then I would default to having a single TaskManager with 16 slots available to that TaskManager.

Is this the optimal configuration? Is there a case where I would prefer 16 TaskManagers with a single slot each or maybe a combination of TaskManager and slots that could take advantage of all 16 CPU cores?

Comment: A cursory glance over the mailing list seems to confirm my hypothesis[1], but it would be good to know more arguments for the inverse (X taskmanagers with 1 slow each) or a hybrid (multiple taskmanagers with a couple slots each).

[1] http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Taskmanager-with-multiple-slots-vs-running-multiple-taskmanagers-with-1-slot-each-td20026.html#a20034

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no optimal configuration because "optimal" cannot be defined in general. A configuration with a single slot per TM provides good isolation and is often easier to manage and reason about.

If you run multiple jobs, a multi-slot configuration might schedule tasks of different jobs to one TM. If the TM goes down, e.g., because either of two tasks consumed too much memory, both jobs will be restarted. On the other hand, running one slot per TM might leave more memory unused. If you only run a single job per cluster, multiple slots per TM might be fine.